# Copy firefox password files from ubuntu 16.4 to ubuntu 20.4

Tags: firefox, passwords, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-20.04

I have Ubuntu 16.4 on my old laptop and it's not working. Now I get this error:

> Error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0' press any key to continue

I have another laptop using Ubuntu 20.4.

I went to my old laptop via windows and using ext2explore to show me my old Ubuntu 16.4 files.

I went to Firefox and copied `key3.db` and logins files.

Can I use this file on my other laptop with Ubuntu 20.4 to retrieve all saved passwords?

Could there be a problem with this approach?

Any new advice?

Also I want to copy all history from old one to new Ubuntu - what is the file name?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try looking under

~/.mozilla/firefox/[Profile Folder]/